# Bootstrap, sizing a well to content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div with a well, is it possible to have the width of the div, size to content? It currently takes the available width (in a col-md-10).

```
<div class="well" style="margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <div class="row">
            <form>

                    <input class="input-lg ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" placeholder="Search for videos on YouTube" style="width: 600px;font-weight: bold" type="text">

                    <button class="btn btn-primary default input-lg" style="margin-top: -5px" type="submit">
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    </button>

            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Maybe... display: inline-block; ?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're trying to do, there is no col-md-10 in your code example.

Comment: The code is just an excerpt. Even without being in a col-md-x, the well takes up the full available width. I'm asking is there a proper way to limit the width of the well without having to set an explicit width on the div.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few scenarios that may help. The easiest thing to do is just place the `well` inside of a `column` that has the appropriate size (in this case less then col-md-10) but if doesn't comply with your layout you could use an [offset](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting).

Otherwise you'll most likely have to set a width for your well that matches whatever content rests inside it.

See working example Snippets (*make sure to view at Full Page)

```css
.well.well-600 {
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h2>Width based on Columns (col-md-6)</h2>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="well">
        <form>
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <input type="text" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" placeholder="Search for videos on YouTube."> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"</button>
      </span>

          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="well">col-md-6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <h2>Width based on Column-Offsets (col-md-10)</h2>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="well">
        <form>
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <input type="text" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" placeholder="Search for videos on YouTube."> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"</button>
      </span>

          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-4">
      <div class="well">col-md-2 col-md-offset-4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <h2>Specific Width (600px) inside a Column (col-md-10)</h2>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="well well-600">
        <form>
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <input type="text" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" placeholder="Search for videos on YouTube."> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"</button>
      </span>

          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="well">col-md-2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <h2>Specific Width (600px)</h2>

  <div class="well well-600">
    <form>
      <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <input type="text" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" placeholder="Search for videos on YouTube."> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"</button>
      </span>

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```